# Problemas para Instalar xdebug para sublime text 3 en windows 10

Tags: php, windows10, sublimetext3, xdebug

El error que me retorna es este:

> Failed loading C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll

No se si el error es por archivo `dll` o es otra cosa.
Y en mi archivo `phoinfo.php`, no me muestra que se habilita. Por ese motivo no puedo probar si funciona el `xdebug` client de **SublimeText3**.

Este mensaje me da la consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Versión del Xampp V3.2.2 para windows 10
- Versión de php 7.0.13
- la instalación del xdebug ya estaba instalada
  https://packagecontrol.io/installation

use este codigo:

```
import urllib.request,os,hashlib;
h = '6f4c264a24d933ce70df5dedcf1dcaee' + 'ebe013ee18cced0ef93d5f746d80ef60'; 
pf = 'Package Control.sublime-package'; 
ipp = sublime.installed_packages_path(); 
urllib.request.install_opener( urllib.request.build_opener( urllib.request.ProxyHandler()) ); 
by = urllib.request.urlopen( 'http://packagecontrol.io/' + pf.replace(' ', '%20')).read(); 
dh = hashlib.sha256(by).hexdigest(); 
print('Error validating download (got %s instead of %s), please try manual install' % (dh, h)) if dh != h else open(os.path.join( ipp, pf), 'wb' ).write(by)
```

- Para el navegador use el **xdebug helper*

Comment: ¿Puedes comentar algo sobre el proceso que seguiste para la instalación? ¿xdebug ya estaba instalado o tuviste que añadirlo? ¿versión de PHP de tu Xampp? ¿Reiniciaste el servidor de xampp en caso de que instalaras xdebug? ¿usaste package control para añadir la extension a sublime u otro método?

Comment: donde da el error? existe esa libreria en la carpeta?

Comment: Proceso de Instalación:
1.
- Versión de php 7.0.13
-Versión Xammp
Si reinicie el servidor xampp.
Use package control, en el sublime text. Xdebug Client.

Comment: Hola gracias por contestar:

- Versiòn de php 7.0.13
- versión de Xampp control V3.2.2
Installation - Package Control

[link](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)